# Overriding default destructor for strings in class implementation

Tags: c++, memory, queue

I am trying to implement a Queue using a sequential list. However, for Queues with string elements, the program crashes.

Below is the relevant portion of the Queue constructor:

```
{
  string *ptr = new string[num];
}
```

After looking for a while, I suspect the issue is with the destructor. In calling the destructor, I am deleting the array pointer of the sequential list and setting it to NULL:

```
{
  delete ptr;
  ptr = NULL;
}
```

However, since the string library provides a default destructor, that deletes the string and I am then trying to delete a non-existent pointer. I think this would be accessing inaccessible memory, which causes a segmentation fault.The Queue implementation works perfectly well for int and double as it currently stands.

I am using templates for int, double and string element types. If the destructor is empty, that would not dynamically deallocate memory for the int and double element Queues.

Is there any easy way to get around this, other than to have an empty class destructor and use the default string destructor?

Comment: Why are you not using `std::string`?  There is no need for any overriding of destructors.  If your template works with `int`, `double`, then it should work with `std::string` with no special need to `delete` anything.

Comment: Post a minimal but complete example that readers can try by just copying and pasting the code and compiling it.

Comment: Alf - this question pertains to a bonus on a class assignment, so I'm trying to be more general. However, thank you for the advice.

Comment: You have `new[]` but not `delete[]`.  That's a bug right there.

Comment: I am using std::string and it does work, but I need to modify the destructor. If I don't delete for the int and double Queues, wouldn't that lead to improper deallocation of dynamic memory?

Comment: John - Yeah, I overlooked that. Changing it to [] seems to fix it for now.

Answer (score 0):

delete deletes just the first instance for non-simple types. delete[] calls dtors for all the instances

I don't know the full scope here, but just for a note, deleting a nullptr is well defined and doesn't do anything.